# Symfony Payum and Stripe error

Tags: symfony, strip, payum

I get the following error when I try to configure stripe gateway:

> Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException
>   Unrecognized options "factory, publishable_key, secret_key" under
>   "payum.ga       teways.stripe_js"

The payum gateway configuration in `config.yml` as follows:

payum:

```
security:
    token_storage:
        AppBundle\Entity\PaymentToken: { doctrine: orm }

storages:
    AppBundle\Entity\Payment: { doctrine: orm }

gateways:
    stripe_js:
        factory: stripe_js
        publishable_key: my publishable key
        secret_key: my secret key
```

The installation was successful the following are required in the composer

```
    "payum/payum-bundle": "0.*",
    "payum/stripe":"0.*",
    "payum/jms-payment-bridge": "0.*",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "@stable"
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems to me the keys names and the factory are not recognised as part of the array under the gateways stripe_js

Comment: You are installing the 0.x version but looking at documentation for 1.x or 2.x version. Please install the latest stable version or use correct documentation for your version of payum

Comment: Thank you, I will try that now

Comment: Maksim, thank you, you have saved my time, your answer is correct. post it as answer in order for me to select it and up vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are installing the 0.x version but looking at documentation for 1.x or 2.x version.

Please install the latest stable version or use correct documentation for your version of payum